# Trouble with Jython GUI

Tags: java, python, swing, user-interface, jython

I am having a problem with my Jython GUI. I need to make the text field appear. I believe I am running into a problem with the Layout, but I am unsure about how to create a new FlowLayout in Jython.

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython

# Created by Joe Castleberry
# 2013 

# Imports
from javax.swing import * 
from java.awt import *

class Window: 
    def __init__(self): 
        # Global variables
        global frame
        global label
        global container
        global text

        # Definition of global variables
        frame = JFrame("Joe's first Java program")
        label = JLabel("Hello World!", JLabel.CENTER)
        container = JPanel()
        text = JTextField(10)

    def builder(self):  
        # Building container
        container.setLayout(None)
        container.setBackground(Color.BLACK)

        # Building frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(container)       # Adding Container to JFrame
        frame.setSize(300,300)
        frame.setVisible(True)
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

        # Adding components to container
         container.add(text)



a = Window()
a.builder()
```

Answer (score 3):

I added the changes with a comment above starting with *CHANGED*. Your code works with minor modifications.

1) Do use layouts, don't set the layout to *None*, no absolute layout manager, etc.

2) Add components to the main content pane container before you pack the frame. 
If not, you'll need to *revalidate* the container among other things (with a possible *repaint* after the frame is visible).

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython

# Created by Joe Castleberry
# 2013 

# Imports
from javax.swing import * 
from java.awt import *

class Window: 
    def __init__(self): 
        # Global variables
        global frame
        global label
        global container
        global text

        # Definition of global variables
        frame = JFrame("Joe's first Java program")
        label = JLabel("Hello World!", JLabel.CENTER)
        container = JPanel()
        text = JTextField(10)

    def builder(self):  
        # Building container
        # CHANGED Removed container.setLayout(None)
        container.setBackground(Color.BLACK)
        # CHANGED Move the add text call here
        container.add(text)

        # Building frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(container)
        frame.setSize(300,300)
        frame.setVisible(True)
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)



a = Window()
a.builder()
```